# Authenticating, multiple calls, and return valid JSON. Photoshelter, but pretty generic

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

Trying to access Photoshelter's API.

It takes 3 calls to get to a JSON object. From there need to parse out the name, values from that object, and construct an image thumbnail, and display in a table.

The issue is how to call the 3 URLs with parameters. If type them into Chrome, it works, each URL return the correct JSON. But need to have them in a single page, just a single link (fake parameters, but think u get the idea).

A. The first is a user + password to authenticate.

https://www.photoshelter.com/psapi/v3/mem/authenticate?api_key=123456789&email=Johnsmith@gmail.com&password=pasword&method=cookie

B. Next is a "gallery location" unique to me.

https://www.photoshelter.com/psapi/v3/mem/organization/O0000uw666660mHBQ/authenticate?api_key=1238363839393

C. Last which returns a JSON formatted object. And then parse out the name:values.

https://www.photoshelter.com/psapi/v3/mem/gallery?api_key=1238363839393

The challenge is to run these all on one page, and parse out the returned JSON, and build a set of thumbnails. Can run them one by one, but not sure how to include all in one page.

Trying to use Javascript and/or jquery. Suggestions welcome. Kind of stuck at the moment.

Comment: so are you saying that each request is dependent on the data from the previous? Specific problem is not clear

Comment: Yes, each one has to be successful, or you are stuck.  Can run them in a browser, same window, one after another, entering each URL, returns the correct JSON, but embedding them all in one page, and having them run without any human intervention is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Those links are useless to us due to no authorization so need to show sample data along with what the dependencies are between each call. Also are you sure that this api is accessible by ajax? Usually when passwords combined with api keys are involved they are not exposed in a browser where anyone can see them

Comment: You are showing your API password !! . You should do  this stuff on your server and then return JSON to the browser (using Ajax or something).

Comment: So this really should always be in node/ php is my thinking. Just what was handed. As say, plugging each one of those lines into a browser, one by one works perfect.  Fast approach is php. Will give that a try.